# Groupbox fit the available space WPF c#

Tags: wpf, groupbox

I am creating this application, I want that Groupbox fit the available space and with margin of 10 in bottom, This is my code :

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="auto">
            <GroupBox x:Name="group" Margin="5,10,0.2,0" Height="300" >
                <DataGrid x:Name="Data"   Margin="348,81,348.4,44.8" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Data" Width="50"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="200"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="200"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="250"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="250"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                </DataGrid>

            </GroupBox>

        </StackPanel>
```

[image]
I have set the height of Groupbox, I am using the app in laptop but when I[! try to use it in desktop it doesn't fit

Comment: this is for the datagrid , but i want the groupbox to fith the size

Comment: Actually, this seems to be answered in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346283/wpf-groupbox-dynamic-height)

Comment: whare i can find the answer

Comment: `x:Name` is a code smell, also you have a margin set on the data grid, which will make it not resize correctly or at all. Stack Panel is a bad idea as it will shrink it's content. Show us the root of the xaml as well.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the stack panel with a grid, and then change the GroupBox height to auto.

```
<Grid>
    <GroupBox x:Name="group" Margin="5,10,0.2,0" Height="auto">
        <DataGrid x:Name="Data"   Margin="348,81,348.4,44.8" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Data" Width="50"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="200"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="200"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="250"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="250"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>

    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lose the StackPanel and replace it with a grid, and set the Vertical alignment of the GroupBox to bottom:

```
 <Grid>
    <GroupBox x:Name="group" Margin="0,0,0,10" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <DataGrid x:Name="Data"   Margin="348,81,348.4,44.8" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Data" Width="50"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="200"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="200"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="250"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="250"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="data" Width="50"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>

    </GroupBox>

</Grid>
```

Comment: it gave me the same

Comment: @MohamedHocine double-check ur xaml, it shouldn't: https://prnt.sc/ppmh4p

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Margin="348,81,348.4,44.8" HorizontalAlignment="Center"` from `<DataGrid x:Name="Data"   Margin="348,81,348.4,44.8" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  >` .

When you specifically assign margin and horizontal alignment, its constrained. So, remove those two values.

set the vertical alignment to bottom. `VerticalAlignment = "Bottom"`